# Assign attribute values from POST Parameters using jQuery in nested forms through Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm using nested forms ([RailsCast #196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised)) in my Rails application. Here's what my current problem is and what I'd like to do; however, I'm not sure what is the best way to tackle this issue and would love to get some pointers.

I have a `dish` form (`_form.html.haml`) that has some of the following fields:

```
.control-group
  =f.label :menu, :class => 'control-label'
  .controls
    =select("dish", "menu_id", (current_user.has_role? :admin) ? (Menu.all.collect {|m| [ m.name, m.id ] }) : (current_user.menus.all.collect {|m| [ m.name, m.id ] }), {:include_blank => 'Choose a Menu'})
.control-group
  =f.label :name, :class => 'control-label'
  .controls
    =f.text_field :name

.control-group
  =f.label :category_ids, "Category", :class => 'control-label'
  .controls
    =f.collection_select :category_ids, (current_user.has_role? :admin) ? (Category.order(:name)) : (current_user.categories.order(:name)), :id, :name, params[:category_id].nil? ? {} : {:selected => params[:category_id]}, {multiple: true, :class => 'chzn-select'}

  .controls
    %p.help-block
      =link_to_add_fields "Add New Category", f, :categories, "categories"
```

The `=link_to_add_fields` generates a nested form from the `_category_fields.html.haml` file and this function is defined in my `application_helper.rd` as:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, parent)
  new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
  id = new_object.object_id
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
    render(parent + "/" + association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
  end
  link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
end
```

With my `category` partial form (`_category_fields.html.haml`) looking like this:

```
%fieldset
  .control-group
    %h5
      New Category
      
    =f.select("menu_id", (current_user.has_role? :admin) ? (Menu.all.collect {|m| [ m.name, m.id ] }) : (current_user.menus.all.collect {|m| [ m.name, m.id ] }), {:include_blank => 'Choose a Menu'})
    =f.hidden_field :_destroy
    
    =f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name"
    
    =link_to "X", "#", :class => "remove_fields"
```

As you'll notice, the `menu_id` will already be selected and defined by the user in the `dish` form from the dropdown menu:

```
.control-group
  =f.label :menu, :class => 'control-label'
  .controls
    =select("dish", "menu_id", (current_user.has_role? :admin) ? (Menu.all.collect {|m| [ m.name, m.id ] }) : (current_user.menus.all.collect {|m| [ m.name, m.id ] }), {:include_blank => 'Choose a Menu'})
```

But you also notice that I'm forcing the user to reselect the `menu_id` from another dropdown within the `category` partial form from the nested form.

I'd like to have it so that the `menu_id` does not need to be reselected by the user within the `category` nested form and is, instead, assigned to the new `category` item after the user hits the submit button by detecting it from the parameters that are passed to the database.

For example, when you hit the submit button, the Terminal/console displays the following:

```
Started POST "/dishes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-06 09:51:41 -0700
Processing by DishesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tAbx+14Ve22FVimgY0x2d+fbImuG+pjkgC7Zgdco73k=", "dish"=>{"menu_id"=>"1", "name"=>"New Dish", "category_ids"=>["", "2"], "categories_attributes"=>{"1344271336031"=>{"menu_id"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false", "name"=>""}} ... }}
```

And just to reiterate, I want the `menu_id` within the `"categories_attributes"=>{"1344271336031"=>{"menu_id"=>"1"...` to be set by picking up the `"dish"=>{"menu_id"=>"1" ...`.

I'm assuming the best way to do this would be through jQuery but I'm a complete newbie when it comes to jQuery and wouldn't how where to start and what to look for to research online.

Another thing I tried was using callbacks and reading the database after creation but that's unsafe since there are many variables that I'd need to account for.

### Update 1: Almost There But Stuck

Thanks to MurifoX pointers, I am able to assign the `menu_id` through a `hidden_field` within the nested form by picking up the `menu_id` assigned to the `dish`.

However, when I go to create a new Dish and a new Category within the dish form, it throws the validation error I set in place which validates that a category ID has been provided for a new Category object. So basically, the `menu_id` isn't being passed into the `hidden_field` for the new Category object.

On the other hand, I'm able to:

1. Edit a Dish and create a new Category from the nested form.
2. Create a new Category from its own _form.html.haml page.
3. And edit existing Category items.

But I simply can't:

- Create a new Dish AND a new Category item from the nested form at the same time.

Here's my updated code:

**_category_fields.html.haml**

```
...
=f.hidden_field :menu_id, :value => @dish.nil? ? [:dish][:menu_id] : @dish.menu_id
...
```

**categories_controller.rb**

```
def create      
  if @dish.blank?
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])
  else
    @category = Category.new(:menu_id => [:dish][:menu_id], :name => [:category])
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @category.save
      format.html { redirect_to categories_path, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end

def update
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|        
    if @dish.blank?
      if @category.update_attributes(params[:category])
        format.html { redirect_to categories_path, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
      end
    else
      if @category.update_attributes(:menu_id => [:dish][:menu_id], :name => [:category])
        format.html { redirect_to categories_path, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not use the `params[:dish][:menu_id]` that you already have and on the controller, manually set it?

Comment: You mean, in my `_category_fields.html.haml` create a hidden field for `menu_id` and assign the value to `params[:dish][:menu_id]`? Or, could you elaborate? You mean in the `create` function in the `category_controller.rb`?

Comment: Yeah, in the `create` action you have access to the `params[:dish][:menu_id]`, so when you build the other objects, you can set the `menu_id` to each one of them using the params. Don't know if i am being clear enough.

Comment: Thanks MurifoX. I was able to get the `menu_id` assigned but am running into an issue when I go to create a new Dish and a new Category at the same time. I've updated my post with more details of the issue. Would you be able to help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Let me see if i understood your problem correctly. You have a `dish` that `has_many :categories`. A form where you save a dish and 0 or more categories, and you are trying to set a `menu_id` for both of them that comes from a dropdown list, right? If this is right, i believe that all of this should be on `dishs_controller` first. Afterall `dish` is the main object right?

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more? It makes sense that this is all done within the `categories_controller.rd`. How would it look if it were w/i the `dishes_controller.rb`? The only problem I'm really having is that the `hidden_field` value isn't being set to the `[:dish][:menu_id]` value within the `_category_fields.html.haml`